# Where to put a method which uses only public interface of its class?

Tags: object-oriented, c++

For a class like this:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    virtual int GetA();
    virtual int GetB();
};
```

Where should I declare a non-virtual function GetSumOfAB()?

1 - Make it an instance method?

```
class Foo {
  public:
    virtual int GetA();
    virtual int GetB();

    int GetSumOfAB() {
        return GetA() + GetB();
    }
};
```

2 - Make it a static method so it was obvious it is related to the class Foo?

```
class Foo {
  public:
    virtual int GetA();
    virtual int GetB();

    static int GetSumOfAB( Foo& foo ) {
        return foo.GetA() + foo.GetB();
    }
};
```

3 - Or make it a free function?

```
namespace Bar {
    int GetSumOfAB( Foo& foo );
}
```

What do you think?

EDIT:

I received a lot of strange downvotes, so I would like to clarify what the problem is.

GetSumOfAB() is an algorithm which uses public API of the class.
There could be a lot of algorithms.
Should I put all of them into the class as instance methods? Or should I prefer not to make my class large?

Comment: Do you have better example code?  This code, frankly, doesn't do anything useful, so it's difficult to offer an opinion with respect to its implementation.

Comment: 2. Why would you make a static method if it needs an instance to operate on? That's the whole point of an instance method...

Comment: Note that in C++ there are no "methods" at all. It's called *member functions*: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8596481/1116364

Comment: The example is a bit bare but from an OOP perspective it can be seen as a collection of amounts with a Total property. That would make the first option the most appropriate one.

Comment: @DanielJour I fail to see the difference. Structured blocks of code that take parameters, one of which is the instance it was called on, that potentially returns a value.

Comment: @Alexander There's no difference. It's a point of terminology. You could also call them "foo-bar" if you'd define that term accordingly. But that would make it hard to communicate with others. (Most of)  which call them *member functions*, just like the standard does.

Answer (score 2):

I would most certainly go with the first option.

The second option is nonsensical, the whole point of a class method is that it's not dependent on any particular instance of the class. A method that operates on a particular instance is exactly what an instance method is. Just use that.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a non-member function.

If a function can be implemented as a non-member function, it should be implemented as a non-member function.

See this rather long and elaborate article by Scott Meyers that explains [How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197).